# Как отличить обособленное приложение от определяемого слова?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Если *прокуратор Иудеи* является определяемым словом, то перед *Понтий Пилат* нужна запятая, т.к. *Понтий Пилат* в таком случае будет являться обособленным приложением. Но в данном предложении *Понтий Пилат* является определяемым словом для *прокуратор Иудеи*, поэтому запятая не ставится. Как мне отличить где определяемое слово, а где обособленное приложение?

> В белом плаще с кровавым подбоем, шаркающей кавалерийской походкой,
>   ранним утром четырнадцатого числа весеннего месяца нисана в крытую
>   колоннаду между двумя крыльями дворца Ирода Великого вышел прокуратор
>   Иудеи Понтий Пилат (М. Булгаков).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно помнить, что **имена, фамилии, отчества, прозвища людей чаще всего не являются приложениями**: врач Петров (приложение — врач).

Исключением являются  случаи, когда имена, фамилии, прозвища людей вводятся с помощью слов по кличке, по фамилии, по прозвищу;

Поскольку главное слово и приложение могут быть выражены именами существительными, далеко не всегда легко определить, какое из существительных является определяемым словом, а какое — приложением.

Для разграничения определяемого слова и приложения следует учитывать следующие признаки:

- если одно из существительных является подлежащим, то сказуемое согласуется с ним, а не с приложением: Журнал «Итоги» уже продан. — Журнал продан; Девушка-почтальон разносила газеты. — Девушка разносила;
- если при склонении одно из слов сохраняет форму именительного падежа, то это приложение: журнал «Итоги», в журнале «Итоги»;
- в необособленных приложениях при сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени неодушевлённых предметов приложением является имя собственное: река Волга, журнал «Итоги»;
- при сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени (фамилии) человека приложением является имя нарицательное: директор Ушаков, брат Иван;
- при сочетании нарицательных и собственных имен возможны варианты, поэтому в данном случае следует учитывать значение имен существительных **(приложение обычно указывает на качество, свойство, национальность, возраст, профессию, социальное положение, родственные связи предмета).**

По мере развития языка определяемое слово и приложение нередко сливаются в цельное сочетание — один член предложения (княжна Марья, товарищ капитан, капитан Иванов, Волга-матушка, Иван-царевич, Аника-воин, матушка-Земля, матушка-Русь), а иногда и в одно слово (диван-кровать, платье-костюм, хлеб-соль).